# How to put a spinner between a list view and a App Bar

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am currently working on an application to help manage bills. I have an activity that list the bills. I am trying to put a `spinner` between a list of bills and the title at the top. Is there a way to put the `spinner` so that it is at the top of the `listView` but below the app bar.?

This is what the app looks like:

[image]

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateRangeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/date_range"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:textAlignment="center"
        tools:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarBillList"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
        android:id="@+id/bill_dates"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:entries="@array/date_arrays"
            android:prompt="@string/bill_date_prompt"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/listBillView"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_bill_list" app:layout_anchor="@+id/bill_dates" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_bill_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.yourdirectlink.ydlcms.BillListActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_bill_list">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listBillView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: What if you make your parent layout as `LinearLayout`? In that case it is easy to position the layouts vertically.

Comment: What about the `TextView` "dateRangeView"?  where is it supposed to go? Also post your layout file "content_bill_list".

Comment: The "dateRangeView" is kind of ok at the top of the activity. I am debating whether it will be relevant, once I get the selection box (spinner) working. I just put it there because I needed to know what the date range was for the list of bills. I think future state the spinner will serve that purpose and I wont need it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### DISMISS THIS

As suggested in the comments why not use a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and put the spinner as the first child with height wrap_content and then below it the listview with height 0dp and layout_weight set to 1

---

#### NEW PROPOSAL

Take a look a this layout. I already tried at a test app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        <!--app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />-->

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateRangeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/date_range"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:textAlignment="center"
        tools:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:entries="@array/date_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/bill_date_prompt"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/listBillView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarBillList"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


    <include
        layout="@layout/content_bill_list"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bill_dates"/>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have to comment the popup theme because I don't have it.

Also you need to use a theme with **.NoActionBar** because you're suppling the action bar and on the Activity containing this layout you need to call:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Was it what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't understand. I would replace the AppBarLayout with a LinearLayout or would I put the TextView (dateRangeView), progress bar and the included content_bill_list into the LinearLayout that the spinner is already in and adjust that LinearLayout?

Comment: I lines up everything but it used to collapse the heading at the top when I scrolled. I don't have that anymore. Can I still have that ability with this new setup?

Comment: I think the main difference from your original code is the LinearLayout below the AppBarLayout. I guess if you only take that part from my post and keep every other thing as they were before, it should work. (also remove the .NoActionBar an the code in onCreate)